# Physical process of mass creation and destruction via $E=mc^2$

Tags: special-relativity, energy, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

Einstein's famous equation is $E=mc^2$. This is essential in nuclear reactions that are happening in the sun and other stars. They convert matter to energy. But scientists in recent times also converted energy to matter. My question is that  why matter becomes energy in nuclear reactions ?

Answer (score 2):

> They convert matter to energy. ... My question is that how and why matter becomes energy?

Although it is commonly said, it is not actually correct that matter is converted to energy. Energy is not something that exists on its own. It is a property of a system.

For example, a system of an electron and a positron can change into a system of two photons. The system of an electron and a positron had a certain energy, and the system of photons has that same energy. The photons are not pure energy, they have other properties too like spin. The photons are quantum mechanical particles that have energy, just like the positron and electron were.

As far as how it happens, there are many conservation laws: energy, momentum, spin, charge, etc. Any transition which satisfies all of the conservation laws can happen with some probability. Since energy is one such law energy cannot be “converted” to or from matter as that would imply a decrease or increase in energy, which is forbidden.